# Attempting to use a variable set from a read of a .csv file as the pattern to grep a second .csv file

Tags: grep, zsh

I have two .csv files.  The first file has a column of words.  The second has two columns with the first column containing values that match one of the entries in the first file.  I want to read the first file line by line and use each line to make a grep query of the second file.  Current code shown

1. while read line
2. do
3. grep $line ./filetwo.csv
4. done < fileone.csv

This code produces nothing.  If I replace $line with a variable that is not assigned by the read of a file it works perfectly.  I have been looking at this issue for years and have never found an answer to what looks like a simple problem.  I do not understand why a variable assigned by a read of a .csv file does not provide the same results as a variable that is directly assigned.  I am using a zsh shell.

Comment: A not infrequent cause of issues like this is that one or both of the files has DOS-style (CRLF) line endings

Comment: ... see for example [grep command in bash shell loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/536194/grep-command-in-bash-shell-loop)

Answer (score 1):

CSV files are more common in the Microsoft world so you may find that:

- they are encoded in UTF-16 rather than the locale's charset so would need to be converted.
- or they are encoded in UTF-8 but with a byte-order-mark.
- they have CRLF line delimiter.
- their last line is not delimited (so `read` would return false on them).

You can check if that's the case with `file yourfile.csv`.

Then you could do:

```
dos2unix < fileone.csv |
  while IFS=, read -r first rest_if_any_ignored; do
    dos2unix < filetwo.csv | grep -Fe "$first"
  done
```

(note the `-F` for fixed string search instead of the default which would do regex matching (the `re` in `grep`)), but that would be rather inefficient as that runs three commands for each line of `fileone.csv` and each `grep`  processes the contents `filetwo.csv` from the start each time.

That also looks for the `$first` string anywhere in `filetwo.csv`, not just the first column and doesn't do exact matches. For instance, if `$first` is `foo`, that will report both `foobar,other` and `other,foobar` lines. That also doesn't handle CSV quoting. So you may be better off use a language with proper CSV parsing.

If those files are simple CSVs, that is without quoting nor headers, that would be a job for `join` here:

```
preprocess() {
  dos2unix -O -- "$@" | sort -t, -k1b,1
}

join -t, <(preprocess < fileone.csv) <(preprocess < filetwo.csv)
```

For real CSVs, with headers and possibly quoting (including of data containing newline characters), you could use a CSV parser such as `mlr` and [its `join` verb](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-verbs/#join).

For instance, if the first column is called `foo` in `fileone.csv` and `bar` in `filetwo.csv`:

```
mlr --csv join -j foo -r bar -f fileone.csv filetwo.csv
```

That handles CRLF, undelimited lines and UTF-8 with BOM, but not UTF-16 which you'd need to convert to UTF-8 first either with `dos2unix` or `iconv`.

`mlr` can also do simple CSVs and several other  tabulated formats. Check its manual for details.